# JavaMail Send Email from Google Group

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I own a gmail account `person@gmail.com` and a google group `group@gmail.com`. I already linked the group to my account so that on Gmail UI I can use the dropbox to choose to send email from the group address.

So the recipient will see the email is sent from **"group@gmail.com"**. When reply, the replying message is sent to **"group@gmail.com"** as well.

Is there any JavaMail method that allows me to realize this in JAVA?

Comment: The java API does support your use case but it's not a method. You'd have to log into the SMTP server using your credentials but specify the `group@gmail.com` as the  `mail.smtp.from` property.

Comment: do you mean set the group email as the default send address or there is something I have missed?